# How to select all remaining features after a Layer Definition filtering?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a map service that represents the World map with a table with population associated. I would like to filter some of the data matching a criteria and then, select **ALL remaining** features to work with them later, for instance, adding all them to an array.

For example, I can solve the first part of the problem if I create an ArcGIS Dynamic Map Service and apply a Layer Definition filtering to obtain a subset, like filtering countries with an population bigger/smaller than a threshold.

But, once I see on the screen my filtered map, how can I select all remaining features?

Does anyone know? Any Feature Layer magic?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I would use arrays of object ids to do this.  When you initialize the layer, get a list of all the object ids in the layer.  This can be done using the `returnIdsOnly` option on the [REST API query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41980/how-to-select-all-remaining-features-after-a-layer-definition-filtering).

> Note that while there is a limit on the number of features included in
>   the feature set response, there is no limit on the number of object
>   IDs returned in the ID array response. Clients can exploit this to get
>   all the query conforming object IDs by specifying `returnIdsOnly=true`
>   and subsequently requesting feature sets for subsets of object IDs.

Once you have an array of all object IDs, you could use client side language (e.g. javascript) to generate a list of "all remaining" features, and query those by passing that as a REST query parameter `objectIds`.  I believe the javascript API wraps this REST call using the FeatureLayer's [queryIds method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/featurelayer.html#queryids).

Keep in mind that ObjectIds are not necessarily continous - numbers can be skipped.